# Android : how can i get activity value by using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to make loading page between activities.
 So, I tried to make new Activity only for loading but there is one problem.
 I can't get 'Activity' value by using intent like,

```
 Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class); 
 i.putExtra("Activity", activity1.this);
 startActivity(i);
```

However, I can't get this Extra value because there is no 'getActivityExtras()'.
 How can I do this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// define NAME in Activity 1
public const NAME = "Activity1";       

Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class); 
i.putExtra("Activity", "Activity1.NAME");
startActivity(i);

// in Activity 2
activity = getStringExtra("Activity");

switch(activity) {
 case Activity1.NAME:
 // do whatever you want here
 break;
```

}

Comment: thx for answer though I'm very late...
I found another way to solve this problem..! - using getSerializable() can get activity's context. Plz ref :)

Answer (score 3):

You can not get activity from intent object, but you can get activity name from this method:

```
intent.getComponent().getShortClassName()
```

**Note:**
If your activity file is in folder, result of method contains folder name.
example for activity file inside "activities" folder:

```
.activities.SubActivity1
```

and must use from:

```
intent.getComponent().getShortClassName().split("\\.")[2]
```